# Accents resources?

Tags: resource-request, accent, prosody

What are some good beginner's introductions to accents? In English (accents, I mean, generally; but English sites or books)?

At this moment I'm primarily interested in accents on the level of the single syllable, but I'm bit lost in terminology: prosody, accentology, stress, pitch, intonation... and can't find the starting point, with names of  *syllable accents*, their notation, maybe codification etc.

Comment: "Accents" are variations in pronunciation that can be personal, local, social, affected by other native languages, or some combination of these. You really need to understand phonetics, and you should understand sociolinguistics, in order to understand accents. Phonetics is a natural science that studies hyman speech sounds, their production, their perception, and their variations. Sociolinguistics is a social science that studies the correlations between human speech variations and the socioeconomics of speech groups.

Comment: As for data, you can get all the English accents you want (foreign and domestic) at the [George Mason Accent Archive](http://accent.gmu.edu/).

Comment: British English http://www.routledge.com/books/details/9781444121384/ , http://www.bbc.co.uk/voices/ and http://sounds.bl.uk/Sound-Maps/Accents-and-dialects

Comment: @jlawler Great typo, very amusing (I'm sure Larry would be)!

Comment: Yes, I'm sure he'd be very amused. Took me a minute.. :-)